# Why does the cast from double precision to numeric round to 15 significant digits?

Tags: postgresql, cast, floating-point

The cast from `double precision` (`float8`) to `numeric` rounds to 15 significant decimal digits, thereby losing information. Clearly, more precision is possible. The cast to `bigint` (for values within its range) preserves more precision:

```
SELECT f8          AS float8
     , f8::bigint  AS to_bigint
     , f8::numeric AS to_numeric
FROM  (
   VALUES
     ('8217316934885843456'::float8)
   , ('8217316934885843457')
   , ('8217316934885844479')
   , ('8217316934885844480')   
   , ('8217316934885845503')
   , ('8217316934885845584')   
   ) t(f8);

        float8         |      to_bigint      |     to_numeric      
-----------------------+---------------------+---------------------
 8.217316934885843e+18 | 8217316934885842944 | 8217316934885840000
 8.217316934885844e+18 | 8217316934885843968 | 8217316934885840000
 8.217316934885844e+18 | 8217316934885843968 | 8217316934885840000
 8.217316934885845e+18 | 8217316934885844992 | 8217316934885840000
 8.217316934885845e+18 | 8217316934885844992 | 8217316934885840000
 8.217316934885846e+18 | 8217316934885846016 | 8217316934885850000
(6 rows)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=89538ad467b701f391aae67a8bff3ff1)*

I picked values at boundaries where `float8` flips a bit - at least in my local installation (Postgres 13, Ubuntu, Intel CPU), and on dbfiddle, and in a hosted DB on AWS, too).

Some relevant quotes from the current manual (Postgres 14):

In the [overview of numeric types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-TABLE)

> `double precision` ... **15 decimal digits** precision

In the [chapter for floating point numbers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT):

> The `double precision` type has a range of around `1E-307` to `1E+308` with a **precision of at least 15 digits**.

And:

> By default, floating point values are output in text form in their shortest precise decimal representation; the decimal value produced is closer to the true stored binary value than to any other value representable in the same binary precision. (However, the output value is currently never *exactly* midway between two representable values, in order to avoid a widespread bug where input routines do not properly respect the round-to-nearest-even rule.) This value will use **at most 17 significant decimal digits** for `float8` values, and at most 9 digits for `float4` values.

Bold emphasis mine.

So why not preserve *at most 17 significant decimal digits* in the cast to `numeric`? The cast to `bigint` does better!

This has counter-intuitive (at least for me) effects. A cast to `numeric` loses precision, while a cast to `bigint` does not.

```
test=> SELECT '8217316934885843456'::float8 = '8217316934885843456'::float8::bigint::float8
test->      , '8217316934885843456'::float8 = '8217316934885843456'::float8::numeric::float8;
 ?column? | ?column? 
----------+----------
 t        | f
```

It's a notoriously tricky matter. So maybe there are good reasons for capping at 15 digits that I fail to see?
Or could Postgres do better?

Answer (score 2):

Bigint will be more precise anyway (19 digits at most).
The observed behavior of conversion between `float8` and `numeric` makes sense if we assume that `extra_float_digits` value is set to 0;

```
SET extra_float_digits = 0;
SELECT '8217316934885843456'::numeric::text
UNION ALL
SELECT '8217316934885843456'::float8::text
UNION ALL
SELECT '8217316934885843456'::float8::numeric::text
```

result:

```
8217316934885843456
8.21731693488584e+18
8217316934885840000
```

If you increase `extra_float_digits` (the default value is 1, but you can increase it up to 3), the precision of conversion to float8 changes (but not past 1 digit), but the precision of conversion from float8 to numeric doesn't change. It likely means somewhere in Postgres code it uses "old" precision logic for this conversion. It could be a bug or an oversight, but there could be a genuine reason for that (which I don't know unfortunately).

> For compatibility with output generated by older versions of PostgreSQL, and to allow the output precision to be reduced, the extra_float_digits parameter can be used to select rounded decimal output instead. Setting a value of 0 restores the previous default of rounding the value to 6 (for float4) or 15 (for float8) significant decimal digits.

Comment: Yes, I suspect some outdated code in the cast, too. Just never got around to file a bug report. (Also, not too many people seem to care.)